# Regex lazy quantifier behave greedy

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a text like this;

`[Some Text][1][Some Text][2][Some Text][3][Some Text][4]`

I want to match `[Some Text][2]` with this regex;

`/\[.*?\]\[2\]/`

But it returns `[Some Text][1][Some Text][2]`

How can i match only `[Some Text][2]`?

Note : There can be any character in Some Text including `[` and `]` And the numbers in square brackets can be any number not only 1 and 2. The `Some Text` that i want to match can be at the beginning of the line and there can be multiple `Some Text`s

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znhes2jy/2/)

Answer (score 3):

The `\[.*?\]\[2\]` pattern [works like this](https://regex101.com/r/ZJzdoP/1):

- `\[` - finds the leftmost `[` (as the regex engine processes the string input from left to right)
- `.*?` - matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, *but* as many as needed for a successful match, as there are subsequent patterns, see below
- `\]\[2\]` - `][2]` substring.

So, the `.*?` gets expanded upon each failure until it finds the leftmost `][2]`. **Note the lazy quantifiers do not guarantee the "shortest" matches**.

**Solution**

Instead of a `.*?` (or `.*`) use **negated character classes** that match any char but the boundary char.

```
\[[^\]\[]*\]\[2\]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJzdoP/2).

Here, `.*?` is replaced with `[^\]\[]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`.

**Other examples**:

- Strings between angle brackets: `<[^<>]*>` matches `<...>` with no `<` and `>` inside
- Strings between parentheses: `\([^()]*\)` matches `(...)` with no `(` and `)` inside
- Strings between double quotation marks: `"[^"]*"` matches `"..."` with no `"` inside
- Strings between curly braces: `\{[^{}]*}` matches `"..."` with no `"` inside

In other situations, when the starting pattern is a multichar string or complex pattern, use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970), `(?:(?!start).)*?`. To match `abc 1 def` in `abc 0 abc 1 def`, use `abc(?:(?!abc).)*?def`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?!^)(\[[A-Z].*?\]\[\d+\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qI4aA6/5)

Comment: It does not return the value i want if there is a `[` or `]` in `Some Text`

Comment: could you provide all the possibilities?

Comment: I am sorry @Avinash Raj But your answers make me remember other possibilities. The `Some Text` that i want to match can be at the beginning of the line and there can be multiple `Some Text`s

Comment: that's what i said before. Please post some examples for all the possible matches and also for not.

Comment: please not in the literal form it's hard to understand.

Comment: see here http://regex101.com/r/qI4aA6/6 it matches any number the corresponding `[]` if there are any number of sometext or [] present in it. THe main part in the above regex is `\[[A-Z]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60293/discussion-between-mod-and-avinash-raj).