# Regex to capture first group in brackets before a match. Here: hexcolor within {my text}{#F00}

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert custom syntax into a `<span>` with a `color` attribute.

Example input:

```
First {text with link}{https://www.stackoverflow.com/}. Followed by {colored text}{#85144B}.
```

For now I used in Javascript:

```
line = line.replace(/\{(.*?)\}\{(#[0-9,A-F,a-f]{3}|#[0-9,A-F,a-f]{6})\}/g, '<span style="color:$2">$1</span>');
```

which matches/replaces if there is only one occurence of those brackets `{}`.

However, with the example above it matches all the other brackets too (greedy?):

[image: regex101 A]

[image: regex101 B]

Being still a Regex rookie I cannot figure out how to ONLY match the first group (enclosed in brackets) before the hexcolor block.

I tried lookahead assertion and negative lookahead assertion but failed.

Comment: `\{(.*?)\}` => `\{([^{}]*)\}`, see https://regex101.com/r/gluiIj/2

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me one hour of trial and error.  And I now see the NOT operator. Perfect.

Comment: I added the curly braces example at [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592173/3832970).